# Android-Java: Get data from many EditText and set each one to different int variable -Two array with for loop

Tags: java, android

This code always returns ZERO

I have five `EditText` (I already define them) and I want to get Integer value from them and assign each one to a different `int` variable (I already define them too), then I want to change each alone.

This is my code:

```
    EditText[] texts = {editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4, editText5};
    int[] ints = {one, two, three, four, five};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(texts[i].getText().toString());
    }

    int sum = one + (two * 2) + (three * 3) + four + five;

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

***Edit:***
I solved it like this: (Thx @Ankita for hint)

```
    String[] texts = {editText1.getText().toString(), editText2.getText().toString(), editText3.getText().toString(),
            editText4.getText().toString(), editText5.getText().toString()};
    int ints[] = new int[texts.length];
    int sum;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(texts[i]);
    }

    int one = ints[0], two = ints[1], three = ints[2], four = ints[3], five = ints[4];
    sum = one + two *2 + three * 3 + four + five;
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

Comment: What are you getting exactly in textview?

Comment: I'm getting only `0`

Comment: Ok let me check I think you made some changes recently.

Comment: I put one=1,two=2,three=3,four=4 and five=5 & editText1=20, editText2=20 .... editText5=20. And getting the result in sum=23.

Comment: Yes, because it wasn't clear.

Comment: According to you what should be in sum = ?

Comment: sum = one + (two * 2) + (three * 3) + four + five , and one, two, ... values; I want to get them from EditText when I run app in my phone.

Comment: then take it from editTexts why you need an additional array for this.

Comment: because I have more than five EditTexts, the code without array and for loop is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes in your code -

```
  String[] texts = {editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4, editText5};

    int ints[]=new int[texts.length];
    int sum=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextSum = findViewById(R.id.txt_sum);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(texts[i]);
            Log.e("ints[i]", String.valueOf(ints[i]));
            sum=sum+ints[j];
        }
        mTextSum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it with a hint from you, but you can't define array as String and its arguments as EditText, I will write thesolution in edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost working already.  You don't need that intermediate array of integers.  Just sum directly in the loop:

```
EditText[] texts = {editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4, editText5};
int sum = 0;

for (int i=0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(texts[i].getText().toString());
}

textView.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that I didn't explain clearly in the question,  but this is an example of my original code, I want to change the value of each one of the Integers after that, not only the sum of them.